# How can 5G impact the reliability of some voice calls and data?

Tags: iphone, network, cellular-data

In the iPhone (in this case 15, with iOS 17), when I go to **Mobile service > Mobile data options > Voice & Data** and 5G is enabled (**On** or **Auto**) the following message is displayed:

> 5G may impact battery life and reliability of some voice calls and data.

[image: settings screenshot]

It’s understandable that 5G impacts battery life. But I could not find any documentation that implied that the reliability of voice calls or cellular data could potentially have a negative impact, due to 5G.

Why is this disclaimer relevant? Where can we find more info about this?

Comment: what is your signal strength on 5G

Comment: This might be provider-specific, I don‘t see the third paragraph on my iPhone.

Comment: Full strength in a good location, full 5G support by the carrier. Still there should be a technical description about this somewhere.